# Adding a var to the url won't work! AJAX/ JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

Here's the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          var abcd= Computing;
   var req=$.ajax({
        url: "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/soc/search?q="+abcd,
        dataType:"jsonp"

    });

req.done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var unorderedList =$("<ul />", {
        "id" : "titles"
    });
    var displayDetails =$("<div />" ,{
        "id" : "details"
    });


    var arrayL = data.length;
    var outputString ='';

        for(var i=0; i<arrayL; i++){

            outputString= data[i].title;
            var listItem = $("<li />", {
                id:i,
                text: outputString
            });
            unorderedList
            .append(listItem);
        }
        $("body")
        .append(unorderedList)
        .append(displayDetails);
        $("body").on("click", "li", function(){
            var i = parseInt(this.id);
            $("#details").html(function(){
                return data[i].description;
            });
        });
});
});
```

If I replace the variable abcd with Computing into the URL, voila it will work. 
I'm trying to store in that variable inputs from my HTML page, which is basically a search engine. The user's input needs to appear in that abcd variable, not sure if I need to echo that or not. anyone pls help?

Thanks

Comment: what is Computing, it doesn't look like it's defined in your code. is it a string? if so you need to put quotes around it

Comment: Yeah that's working now, I am trying to do it bit by bit.
Now after I see I can use a variable there, I am now trying to find out how to store user's input into that variable.

Comment: You should use getJSON instead (it supports cors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the word "Computing" is a string, you need to wrap it in quotes.

```
var abcd = "Computing";
```

Comment: never thought about that, it worked with quoting the Computing.
Also, how to store into that variable user input from my index.html?

Comment: Glad to help. Can you please accept this answer if that fixed everything?  Thanks!

Comment: var abcd= "<?php echo $searchbar?>";

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['searchbar'])){
 $searchbar=$_POST['searchbar'];
 }
 
 
 else{
  $searchbar=' ';
 }
 $searchbar=urlencode($searchbar);
 json_encode($searchbar);
 
  echo "<p></p>";
?>

this is what I am talking about.

sorry about the bad editing, idk how to edit it as a code.